# Caffe Boost Shared_Ptr SegFault in Net::Init?

Tags: shared-ptr, caffe

Caffe crashes using Boost shared_ptr inside Net::Init

```
_net.reset(new Net<float>(path + modelProtoTxt, TEST));
```

Note the BAD 'this' Pointer for RNG (0x1):

[image]

It actually dies inside BaseConvulutionLayer::Setup --> XavierFiller::Fill --> Caffe::RNG (corrupt this pointer)

[image]

### Compiler/Linker Flags

g++ mytest.cpp -o testcaffe -lcaffe -lglog -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_system -std=c++11 -g -O0

The same version of libcaffe.so works with a previously-compiled application using the same model files (prototxt, etc.)

Could this be the result of a mismatch of g++ build/link flags and the version of boost?

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0
```

Comment: Shouldn't this have been posted on the Caffe mailing list or issue tracking system?

Comment: I suspect that it is not a Caffe bug, but some incompatibility between libraries or compiler flags. I'm hoping that someone who knows about Boost or Linux linker gotchas will have an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Your first port of call should still be the people who actually use and intimately know the library.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet Thanks. I posted an issue on the Caffe GitHub site.